# how to append to a dictionary values from another dictionary if keys match

Tags: python, dictionary

let's say I have two dictionaries

```
dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':f}
dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}
```

I'd like a function that returns the second dictionary as

```
dict_2 ={'A': 'a', 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}
```

which is matching the keys of dict_1 against those in dict_2. If one matches replace the value in dict_2 with the value in dict_1 for that key. Otherwise nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to do this by iterating over `dict_2`'s items and using `dict_1.get()` providing default value as `dict_2` corresponding value -

```
>>> dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':f}
>>> dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}
>>> for k,v in dict_2.items():
...     dict_2[k] = dict_1.get(k,v)
...
>>> dict_2
{'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None, 'L': None, 'A': 'a'}
```

---

Same using dict comprehension -

```
>>> dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':f}
>>> dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}
>>> dict_2 = {k:dict_1.get(k,v) for k,v in dict_2.items()}
>>> dict_2
{'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None, 'L': None, 'A': 'a'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to find the common keys, and iterate over them like this:

```
dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':f}
dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}

for key in set(dict_1.iterkeys()) & set(dict_2.iterkeys()):
    dict_2[key] = dict_1[key]
```

This should be much less computational expensive if it's relatively few common entries compared to the total number of entries in the dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dict comprehension  and `if else` to do it :

```
dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':f}
dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}
dict_2={a : dict_1[a] if a in dict_1 else dict_2[a] for a in dict_2.keys() }
print dict_2
```

**output:**

```
{'A': 'a', 'H': None, 'I': None, 'L': None, 'G': None}
```

But this creates a new dict object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.viewkeys` to find the common keys:

```
dict_1 ={'A': 'a', 'B':'b', 'C': 'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e','F':'f'}
dict_2 ={'A': None, 'G': None, 'H': None, 'I': None,'L': None}

for k in dict_1.viewkeys() & dict_2.viewkeys():
    dict_2[k] = dict_1[k]

print(dict_2)
{'A': 'a', 'H': None, 'I': None, 'L': None, 'G': None}
```

For python3 just use `.keys` as it returns a [dictionary-view-object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) not a list:

```
for k in dict_1.keys() & dict_2.keys():
    dict_2[k] = dict_1[k]

print(dict_2)
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.